# VBA: How to capture a stored procedure return value

Tags: sql, vba, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, vb6

My goal is to execute a sql server stored procedure from a vba function, and to check if the stored procedure returned any records.

In the vba code I gotten this far:

```
Function TestStoredProcedure()

    Dim strMsg As String

    Dim ADOCon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ADOQD As ADODB.Command
    Dim ADORS As ADODB.Recordset

    Set ADOCon = New ADODB.Connection
    ADOCon.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString("Dev")
    ADOCon.CommandTimeout = 0
    ADOCon.Open

    Set ADOQD = New ADODB.Command
    ADOQD.ActiveConnection = ADOCon
    ADOQD.CommandTimeout = 0

    ADOQD.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    ADOQD.CommandText = "mn_CheckForInvalidEntries"

    'Execute
     Set ADORS = ADOQD.Execute

    If ADORS.RecordCount > 0 Then

    strMsg = "The SLI Search Feed was not successful."
            MsgBox strMsg, vbExclamation, "foo"
    Else
        strMsg = "The SLI Search Feed successful."
            MsgBox strMsg, vbExclamation, "foo"
    End If

    ADOCon.Close
    Set ADOQD = Nothing
    Set ADOCon = Nothing
    strMsg = ""

End Function
```

And the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mn_CheckForInvalidEntries]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT
        [ProductID]
    ,   [ForSale]
    FROM [Product]
    WHERE [ProductID] IN
        (
         SELECT
             [SearchIndex].[ProductID]
         FROM [dbo].[SearchIndex]
         INNER JOIN [ProductData]
             ON [dbo].[SearchIndex].[ProductID] = [ProductData].[ProductID]
         WHERE [ForSale] = 1
                     AND [SearchIndex].[ProductID] NOT LIKE 'mn[d-g]%'
                     AND [Record] IS NULL
                     AND [SearchIndex].[ProductID] NOT LIKE 'mn[a-z]%'
END;
```

If I could get any help in getting the part of the check if the sp returned any values, that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: That procedure looks like it returns rows, so have you tried assigning an ADO Recordset to the return value of `Execute` ?  `Set rs = ADOQD.Execute()`   Then check for `rs.EOF` and proceed accordingly.

Comment: I have, and what I get in return is -1. I am updating my vb code so that you can see what I have tried whilst waiting for some comments, recommendations.

Comment: Don't use `Recordcount` (which only really works with specific cursor types) to determine if there are any records: `ADORS.EOF` will be True if nothing was returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store the results you can use a recordset.

```
Dim adoRs As ADODB.Recordset
Set adoRs = ADOQD.Execute
```

Then you can ask whether the recordset is empty.

```
isEmpty = (adoRs.BOF And adoRs.EOF)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you want to do is run a stored procedure from Excel, right? Here are two options for you to try.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Working2()

Dim con As Connection
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strConn As String

Set con = New Connection
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "Data Source=LAPTOP\SQL_EXPRESS;"
strConn = strConn & "Initial Catalog=Northwind;"
strConn = strConn & "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

con.Open strConn

'Put a country name in Cell E1
Set rst = con.Execute("Exec dbo.TestNewProc '" & ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Text & "'")

'The total count of records is returned to Cell A5
ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
con.Close

End Sub


Sub Working()


Dim con As Connection
Dim rst As Recordset

Set con = New Connection
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=LAPTOP\SQL_EXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Set rst = con.Execute("Exec dbo.[Ten Most Expensive Products]")
'Results of SProc are returned to Cell A1
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
con.Close
End Sub
```